# Why is my global variable not initialized after AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-activity

I have a global variable in my class called `String authToken`. In this class I have an AsyncTask like below and the `onPostExecute` method of sets the global variable.

```
class AuthToken extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        MyAccount myAccount = new MyAccount(getApplicationContext());
        return myAccount.getAuthToken();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String fetchedToken) {
        authToken = fetchedToken; //assign it to global variable
        Log.d("Inside token: ", authToken);
    }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
new AuthToken().execute();
Log.d("authToken: ", authToken+""); //print the fetched token
```

For some reason, even though the log message in `onPostExecute` shows the authToken but after the call to `execute()` when I print authToken...it prints nothing:

So in my logs I see:

```
D/Inside token:﹕ 75e7d526-d0eb-4cb2-b294-a57e5dc2e5e4
D/authToken:  ]
```

**Question**

Why isn't my global variable set after the `onPostExecute`?

Answer (score 3):

the log prints nothing because your asynctask did not finish by the time it hit the log line. so you will see nothing.

you variable is being set though

AsyncTask starts a new thread so after it preforms `new AuthToken().execute();` it does the log. if it waited for the asynctask to finish before it printed the log it would defeat the purpose of an async task

Comment: I understand. But then how am I expected to do something like this: In my main activity I want to fetch the authToken and after fetching it I want to see whether it is set (with `if` condition). If it is - then proceed, if it isn't - then show log inactivity. ....

Comment: do anything you want with your token it in your `onPostExecute` that is the only way to know when your task finished. set a callback or something to indicate if you got the token or not in your onPostExecute